# Powershell Directory.Name return the trailing separator?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing my first powershell script:

```
foreach ($UserDir in Get-ChildItem -Path $NetworkLocation) 
{
    # if the item is a directory, then process it.
    if ($UserDir.Attributes -eq "Directory")
    {
        $Dir = $UserDir.Name
        Remove-Item $Dir +"*" -recurse
    }
}
```

Will $Dir end with a trailing "\" so I can just add a * to delete all files in that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't supply a trailing slash.

```
PS C:\> $dirlist=get-childitem c:\
PS C:\> $dirlist[4].name
PerfLogs
PS C:\>
```

Nor will it supply full path:

```
PS C:\> $dirlist=get-childitem C:\windows
PS C:\> $dirlist[3].name 
assembly
PS C:\> $dirlist[3].fullname
C:\Windows\assembly
```

That is provided through "fullname", which also doesn't provide a trailing slash. However, Remove-Item doesn't need slashes!

In summary, to remove all files in a directory and all files in it's sub-directories, use:

```
Remove-Item $Dir -recurse
```

where

```
$Dir = $UserDir.Fullname
```

Comment: To remove all files do you not do: Remove-Item $Dir +"\*" -recurse? I thought you needed the \ to use the *?

Comment: The recurse parameter tells it to do the removal at this location "$Dir" and all child-locations. Its dos equivalent is `rmdir /s`. If all you want to do is remove all files in a location, but leave any sub-directories intact, you'd use wildcards without the `-recurse` parameter.

Comment: I'm looking to delete everything in $Dir, files and sub-folders (and everything in those)

Comment: @SteB In that case, `Remove-Item $Dir -recurse` should be sufficient, so long as `$Dir=$UserDir.Fullname`